# How to use intelligence in Scion?

Tags: scion

I wanted to know how to use or what is the point of intelligence in Scion?

The Scion game I am playing in I have my character with high intelligence but have no idea what to use it for.

Comment: I would think the usage were obvious (any time you have to do something that requires your character to be smart as opposed to quick thinking - Wits). Any chance you could clarify what TYPE of information you're looking for?

Answer (score 5):

Intelligence can be used to modify skills like Occult, Academics, Research, Investigation and so forth.  You could use intelligence to locate artifacts of power, find information in myths and legends or to sort out traps or puzzles while adventuring.  You can use it to circumvent and out-think your opponents.  Not from Scion, but think Ozymandias from Watchmen or Kisuke Uarahara from Bleach or Shikamaru from Naruto.  For ideas you might also check TV Trope's entries on Science Hero and Guile Hero (the latter could also have strong Social attributes).

Answer (score 2):

Well Intelligence generally corresponds to how smart you are so if the party needs to know which Titan is associated with the obscure cult you just broke up and all you have is this glyph to work with you're probably the guy.  Also if there's any math that needs to be done you'd be the go to guy since you can most likely calculate Pi to it's 1000th digit nevermind that you've also memorized it to it's 10,000 digit just for fun while completing your 4th PhD dissertation.

Maybe more succinctly put: you're the guy who just knows things or can figure them out (although how quickly you can figure them out is probably influenced by your Wits score).